# How can I locate a textarea in an html code and modify the text inside the label in Python with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, textarea

I'm looking for ways to enter a text and submit it in Python with Selenium WebDriver

I have read and studied the Selenium page on the location of the elements

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

but I have found no way to locate the "texarea" of ​​my interest

I have to locate, insert the text and submit it in this tag:

```
<textarea aria-label="Aggiungi un commento..."
placeholder="Aggiungi un commento..." class="Ypffh" 
autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;">HERE MY
TEXT
</textarea>==$0
```

I try

```
a = WebDriverWait(browser,5,1).until
(expect.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//aria-
label[@placeholder='Aggiungi un commento...']")))  

a.send_keys('Fabio')
```

The error is:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect xpath. try this xpath,

```
a = WebDriverWait(browser,5,1).until
(expect.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//textarea[contains(@aria-label,'Aggiungi un commento')]")))
```

Hi Sureshmani. 
I try your answer but, but after adding to the script

```
a.send_keys('text')
```

return error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:    
element not interactable
```

Comment: Instead of visibility of the element, try wait until elementToBeClickable

Answer (score 0):

The error was in a var to define element.

```
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/Bz0N9HMoS2t/')
a = WebDriverWait(browser,5,1).until 
(expect.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
"//textarea[contains(@placeholder,'Aggiungi un commento')]"))).click()


b = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[contains(@placeholder,'Aggiungi
un commento')]")

b.send_keys('1')
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, '_0mzm- sqdOP yWX7d
')]").click()
time.sleep(56)
```